# Negative questions : Normal Vs Explanation seeking

Tags: grammar

I'm pretty sure this question is basic and may be a duplicate to any existing ones.

> 授業があるんじゃない?
>
> 授業がない?

1. Isn't there a class?
2. There is no class?

Seems similar to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

授業があるんじゃない？
This would be said by your roomate who knows for sure that you have a class that given day, to you, who are still in your pajamas despite the class starting soon. (This ん is tricky. If you simply asked 授業があるの？then such nuance would not be included, and it would be a simple question: "Do we have a class today?").
Therefore the above could be translated as, "You do have a class today, right?".

授業がない？
This is just a simple question. You came to the classroom late, yet the teacher has not arrived yet. You ask one of the classmates, "(So) there is no class?".